# PHPMailer returns error with ajax but still sends emails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, email

Running into an issue with PHPMailer that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I have a simple form set up with AJAX and PHP. The input values are sent to the php checked for validation. Upon approval, PHP grabs all the pertinent data (name, email, message, etc) creates a message to send back to the site admin (info@email.com).

This all works, but every time it returns the error function from the ajax request. It's driving me crazy especially since the form itself submits, validates and sends the email. Not sure whats happening exactly but my code is pretty bare and nothing fancy is happening but I'm getting an odd error.

```
<form id="form-contact" method="POST" action="form-contact.php" role="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group name-group">
                    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex="1" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group email-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="2" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group subject-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group message-group">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" tabindex="4" ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="submit" tabindex="4">submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#form-contact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
     type:$(this).attr('method'),
     url: $(this).attr('action'),
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(err){
      console.log('failed');
      console.log(err);
     }
    })
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    require '../includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $data = array();
    $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $errors["name"] = "Name is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])){
        $errors["email"] = "Email is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])){
        $errors["message"] = "Message is required";
    }

    if (! empty($errors)){
        $data["success"] = false;
        $data["errors"] = $errors;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['name'] = $name;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['subject'] = $subject;
        $data['message'] = $message;



    }   
    $name =     filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email =    filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $formMessage =  filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = '<p>The following request was sent from: </p>';
    $message .= '<p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Message: ' . $formMessage .'</p>';


    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                                                    // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'server.bluehost.com';                // Specify main and backup server (this is a fake name for the use of this example)             

    $mail->Username = 'XXXX@XXXX.com';                  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXX';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted                                   
    $mail->Port = 465;                        

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
    $mail->addAddress('XXXX@XXXX.com', 'Person Name');  // Add a recipient

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                               // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: Most likely the PHP is outputting some other content in addition to the JSON (such as a warning or notice), causing the JavaScript to fail to parse the JSON. When you have `dataType : 'json'`, jQuery will run the error ajax handler if it couldn't parse the JSON.

Comment: @MrCode is there a way to determine what other content its producing? And are you implying the 'content' isn't harmful? First time doing this so not sure what to expect.

Comment: @patrick It's right before your `json_encode()` line... You should add all messages to your `$data` array.

Comment: @jeroen do you have an example? Not sure what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is expecting back json as you are specifying that. So you need to make sure that you output valid json. You can do that using `json_encode()` but you will have to make sure that only that gets returned to the browser and nothing else.

So you should change:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';         // No other echoes except the very last one
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;  // and here
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';                 // and here

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

to something like:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
   $data['error']['title'] = 'Message could not be sent.';
   $data['error']['details'] = 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

$data['success']['title'] = 'Message has been sent';

echo json_encode($data);
```

Note that other - unintended - output by your php script could include things like php warnings but you can check the exact output in the javascript console.

Comment: Finally got it to work. IT was a mixture of this and just where I was actually 'echo'ing the $data. 

The $errors data was being passed back as JSON that wasn't actually specifying my errors, just a big ol' Object log. Moving the <code>echo json_encode($data)</code> script to outside of my if/else allowed it to log any data that came through. 

Thanks, Jeroen!

Comment: As jeroen says, you cannot echo if it's not json. So if you are using class.smtp.php or class.pop3.php, you must comment some echoes before using it on ajax